# Hibernate fetching parent/child object as a row instead of parent with collection obj

Tags: java, hibernate

The problem in fetching.
I have class A and B
Table A , B

CLASS A:

```
private Integer id;
private String name;
private Set<B> bs = new HashSet<B>(0);

public A() {
}

public A(String name, Set<B> bs) {
    this.name = name;
    this.bs = bs;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "name", length = 45)
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "a")
public Set<B> getBs() {
    return this.bs;
}

public void setBs(Set<B> bs) {
    this.bs = bs;
}
```

CLASS B:

```
private Integer id;
private A a;
private String BName;

public B() {
}

public B(A a){
    this.a = a;
}

public B(A a, String BName) {
    this.a = a;
    this.BName = BName;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "a_id", nullable = false)
public A getA() {
    return this.a;
}

public void setA(A a) {
    this.a = a;
}

@Column(name = "b_name", length = 45)
public String getBName() {
    return this.BName;
}

public void setBName(String BName) {
    this.BName = BName;
}
```

IN DB : A db has 2 records

1. A has a id 1 -> has 2 records of B(table)
2. A has a id 2 -> has 3 records of B(table)

when I query using hql/jpql like below:
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a from A a join fetch a.bs");
        List list = query.getResultList();

I get 5 records in the list instead of 2 with the associated children.

1. A1 -> B1
2. A1 -> B2
3. A2 -> B3
4. A2 -> B4
5. A2 -> B5

instead of getting : 
1. A1-> B collection , 
2. A2-> B collection

I don't want size() approach to load collection data of parent object.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the JPA spec, section 4.4.5.3, an example just like this:

```
SELECT d FROM Department d JOIN FETCH d.employees
```

In this case, while there may only exist 1 `Department` and multiple `Employee` associations, the query result will return multiple rows, each for the associated number of `Employee` joins, despite there only being a single `Department`.

In other words, the JPA spec does not require that queries such as this eliminate duplicates.

In order to acquire the precise list of 2 `A` entities with their collections populated, you'll need to amend your query to include a `DISTINCT`clause.

```
SELECT distinct a FROM A a JOIN FETCH a.bs
```